# Trouble understanding Weyl's unitary trick

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, unitary-matrices

Given a representation of a finite group: $\rho : G \to \text{GL}(V)$, there exists a unitary representation $\tau$ which is isomorphic to $\rho$. I came across Weyl's trick, where you redefine the inner product as follows
$$\langle v,w \rangle = \frac1{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} \langle \rho(g)v, \rho(g)w \rangle_0,$$

where $\langle\ ,\rangle_0$ is the usual inner product. I see the idea of this trick since this new inner product is preserved under $\rho$ i.e. $\langle v,w \rangle = \langle \rho(g')v,\rho(g')w \rangle$ for all $g'\in G$.

I am not familiar with the idea of changing the definition of the inner product to achieve unitarity. As I understand Weyl's trick, the matrices in the set $\{\rho(g):g\in G\}$ and $\{\tau(g):g\in G\}$ are actually identical but the inner product definition is what makes the $\tau(g)$ matrices unitary? Is there a way to translate this back to the usual picture where I use the standard inner product (and therefore a fixed definition of unitarity) and the matrices of the different representations are not identical?

Sorry if there is some vagueness/incorrectness in the question - I am new to group theory.

Comment: Yes. Every inner product is related to every other inner product by a change of coordinates (this is why mathematicians don’t care which one we use here). Explicitly, find an orthonormal basis of the new inner product, then use the change of coordinates taking that basis to your original one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be technical, the way you've defined it, $\rho(g)$s are not matrices, they are functions. Of course, given a choice of ordered basis for $V$, we can write vectors $v\in V$ as coordinate vectors and linear transformations $A\in\mathrm{GL}(V)$ as matrices. What matrices these functions get represented as though depends on which choice of ordered basis (i.e. coordinates) one picks.

I wouldn't say there is a "usual inner product" on an arbitrary vector space $V$. There is just *an* arbitrary inner product that one selects or assumes is given. Note that even having an inner product does not provide enough information to represent the functions $\rho(g)$ as matrices; an inner product does not provide for an ordered basis, which is what is needed for that.

If you assume $\rho$ is a matrix representation from the get-go, that is if you define $\rho:G\to GL_n (\mathbb{C})$ as a representation of $G$ on the vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$, there is no guarantee the matrices $\rho(g)$ are unitary, i.e. there is no guarantee they preserve the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$,

$$ \langle x,y\rangle=\overline{x_1}y_1+\cdots+\overline{x_n}y_n. $$

We can define the $G$-averaged inner product $\langle x,y\rangle_G$ by the unitary trick:

$$ \langle x,y\rangle_G = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} \langle \rho(g)x,\rho(g)y\rangle. $$

Then $\rho(g)$s my not preserve the standard inner product $\langle x,y\rangle$, but they do preserve $\langle x,y\rangle_G$, which when written out will have a different formula than $\langle x,y\rangle$ does.

As I said, the new inner product $\langle x,y\rangle_G$ does not automatically provide a way to rewrite linear operators as matrices. However, if one arbitrarily chooses an ordered unitary basis with respect to $\langle x,y\rangle_G$, we can rewrite the matrices $\rho(g)$ as the matrices $\tau(g)$ using a change-of-basis matrix $M$. Explicitly, these matrices are given by $\tau(g)=M^{-1}\rho(g)M$, where the columns of $M$ are the vectors of the ubasis we chose.

These $\tau(g)$s will be unitary matrices and will preserve the original, standard inner product $\langle x,y\rangle$, because $\tau(g)$'s action on the standard basis corresponds to $\rho(g)$s action on the chosen basis, and $\rho(g)$s action on the chosen basis (unitary with respect to $\langle-,-\rangle_G$) is unitary. Explicitly, because the columns of $M$ are unitary with respect to $\langle-,-\rangle_G$ we can write $Mu$ and $Mv$ as linear combinations of $M$'s columns in order to verify $\langle Mu,Mv\rangle_G=\langle u,v\rangle$. Therefore,

$$ \begin{array}{ll}
 \langle \tau(g)u,\tau(g)v\rangle & = \langle M^{-1}\rho(g)Mu,M^{-1}\rho(g)Mv\rangle \\
& = \langle \rho(g)Mu,\rho(g)Mv\rangle_G \\
& = \langle Mu,Mv\rangle_G \\
& = \langle u,v\rangle
\end{array} $$

so $\tau(g)$ is unitary with respect to $\langle-,-\rangle$.

Comment: @runaway44 if $\tau (g)=M\rho (g)M^{-1}$ then $\rho (g)=M^{-1}\tau (g)M$, so $\rho (g)$ is unitary, being the product of unitary matrices. Contradiction.

Comment: @alexanderyaacov The columns of $M$ are unitary wrt to $\langle-,-\rangle_G$, not $\langle-,-\rangle$, so $M$ is in general not a unitary matrix in the standard sense. Although I did fix a typo: I should have written $M^{-1}\rho(g)M$.

Comment: @runaway44 I checked your claim that $\tau (g)$ is unitary in the standard sense using the example in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/526888/are-all-representations-of-a-finite-group-unitary and it worked. But I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: @alexanderyaacov I added an explanation.