# Weyl's unitary trick S_n

Tags: representation-theory

I am supposed to do Weyl's unitary trick but to show that we have an orthogonal representation. Given are a representation $X : G \rightarrow GL(\mathbb{R})_d$ where G is the symmetric group $S_n$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$). Let $(\cdot, \cdot)$ be the usual inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. We define a new inner product as follows:

$\langle x,y\rangle := \sum_{g \in S_n} (X(g)x, X(g)y)$

I have already shown that this is an inner product, too. Now I want to show that there exists $A\in GL(\mathbb{R})_n$ such that for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have: $\langle Ax,Ay\rangle = (x,y)$.

I have done the following:

$\langle Ax,Ay\rangle = \sum_{g \in S_n} (X(g)Ax, X(g)Ay) = \sum_{g \in S_n} (x, X(g)^TA^TX(g)Ay) = (x, \sum_{g \in S_n}X(g)^TA^TX(g)Ay)$

Equality holds because of the properties of $(\cdot,\cdot)$. So, essentially I just need to show that there exists an $A$ such that $\sum_{g \in S_n}X(g)^TA^TX(g)A = I_n$. Does someone know how I can prove this (if this is correct)?

I have to say that, in general, I have some trouble understanding Weyl's unitary trick and couldn't find a lot of information on it when it is used for representation theory. The best source I could find was:
[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828410/trouble-understanding-weyls-unitary-trick)

---

Solution idea thanks to @JasonDeVito

Let $e_i$ bean orthonormal basis for $(\cdot, \cdot)$ and let $f_i$ be one for $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. We define $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ as the matrix that changes the bases: $Ae_i = f_i$ for all $i\in\{1,...,n\}$. This matrix exists and is orthogonal because the $e_i$ and $f_i$ are both bases over $\mathbb{R^n}$ and we can of course represent $f_i$ by a sum of our $e_i$. The same way can be said the other way around which is why $A$ is invertible.

Now let us look at two random $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. We can represent them with the $e_i$ via:

$x = \sum_i \alpha_i e_i$ and $y = \sum_j \beta_j e_i$.

We yield:

$\langle Ax, Ay\rangle = \langle A\sum_i \alpha_i e_i, A\sum_j \beta_j e_i\rangle = \langle \sum_i \alpha_i f_i, \sum_j \beta_j f_j\rangle
= \sum_i \sum_j \alpha_i \beta_j \langle f_i, f_j\rangle
= \sum_i \alpha_i \beta_i = \sum_i \alpha_i \beta_i (e_i, e_i)
= \sum_i \sum_j \alpha_i \beta_j (e_i, e_j)
= (\sum_i \alpha_i e_i,\sum_j \beta_j e_j) = (x,y)$

Comment: Hint:  If $e_i$ is a orthornormal basis for $(\cdot,\cdot)$, and $f_i$ is an orthonormal basis for $\langle \cdot, \cdot, \rangle$, then try $A$ defined by $Ae_i = f_i$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito i'm sorry i don't know how to work with this hint. So I have $x = \sum_i \alpha_i e_i$ and $y = \sum_i \beta_i e_i$ and then:

$\langle Ax, Ay \rangle = \langle A\sum_i \alpha_i e_i, A\sum_i \beta_i e_i \rangle =\langle \sum_i \alpha_i f_i, \sum_i \beta_i f_i \rangle$

How is that of use for me?

Comment: Use linearity of the inner product, and then the fact that the $f_i$ are $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$- orthonormal to get $\langle Ax, Ay\rangle = \sum_i \alpha_i \beta_i$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks for the reply. I think I am slowly getting there! I now have the following:

$\langle Ax, Ay \rangle = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in S_n} (X(g)Ax, X(g)Ay) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in S_n} (Ax, X(g)X(g)^T Ay) $

If i would be able to remove the $X(g) X(g)^T$ then I see how we yield the sum of $\alpha_i\beta_i$ but can we say that the $X(g)$ are orthogonal? Because I only know that they are invertible

Comment: I think you're thinking too specifically, here, since I haven't actually singled out what the $e_i$ and $f_i$ are.  Instead, just try to use general properties of inner products

Comment: @JasonDeVito I think now I finally have it. I appended what my solution is to the end of my question. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Except for one minor thing, that's exactly what I had in mind.  The one minor thing:  you wrote "This matrix exists and is *orthogonal*...", but then your justification seems to indicate that you meant $A$ exists and is *invertible*.  If you change "orthogonal" to "invertible" there, this would resolve the issue.  Well done!  (By the way, you can also add your answer to the "answer" section, so that this question won't appear as "unanswered" any more.)